# Calculate the integral: $\int_0^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(x^2+y^2)^3dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the integral: $\int_0^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(x^2+y^2)^3dxdy$

I know that I can convert this into polar coordinates as:

$x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$

Given that: $y \le \sqrt{1-x^2} \implies x^2+y^2\le1 \implies r^2\le1$

So the boundary for r is given as $\int_0^1$

Whereas the boundary of the integral for $\theta$ is given as $\int_0^\pi$

Putting all of this together I get:

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^1r^7drd\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

However, the answer is supposed to be$\frac{\pi}{16}$ where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the order of the integral should be $dy$ and then $dx$,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{1} \left[\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(x^2+y^2)^3 dy\right] ~ dx$

$0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ means we are in the first quadrant. So we have $0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

$0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ would mean $0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Ah I see, I was slightly thrown off with the unit circle though I'm sure this will be my final mistake on this given your detailed explanation! Thank you

Comment: @Stackcans you are welcome. I am glad my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, so, you're integrating only on a quarter of a circle. Hence, you should replace $\int_0^\pi$ with $\int_0^{\pi/2}$. What you'll get is exactly half of $\pi/8$.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. The integral is over the right upper *quarter*-circle, not the upper half-circle. :) Drawing pictures is recommended.